# Error installing Cgal-bindings Python

Tags: python, boost, swig, cgal, finite-element-analysis

No matter what method i try, the installation of Cgal-bindigs stops and gives me the next problem:

```
make[2]: ***  No rule to make target «/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so», needed for «/usr/lib/libCGAL_Kernel_cpp.so».  Stop.
make[1]: *** [SWIG_CGAL/Kernel/CMakeFiles/CGAL_Kernel_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Im sure i installed all the prerequisites.I dont understand the error :S. If its usefull I'll paste "make VERBOSE=1" output: http://pastebin.com/V1e9knAh
Please help i need to use it for a Biomedical investigation and the tetrahedralization its fundamental for finite-element-analysis.

Comment: `export LC_ALL=C` would help avoid barbaric messages. Do you have a file `libboost_thread.so` on your machine? Where?

Comment: its in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" before doing "make" i ejecuted "cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/usr/lib/CGAL -DBUILD_PYTHON=ON -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DCOMMON_LIBRARIES_PATH=/usr/lib" should i change it?. What does "export LC_ALL=C"?

Comment: I think your CGAL package is out-of-date (it wasn't recompiled since boost moved from /usr/lib to the multiarch location). You could rebuild the package, or manually fix the file /usr/lib/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake.

Comment: THANKS i fixed /usr/lib/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake manually and that totally worked!. It was a CGAL out-of-date problem like you said. MODIFICATION: "set(CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES      "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so" )" in CGALConfig.cmake file

Comment: please add an answer rather than editing the question with a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a CGAL out-of-date problem. MODIFICATION: "set(CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost‌​_system.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so" )" in CGALConfig.cmake file

The Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cgal/+bug/1242111

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to rerun the configuration and compilation of CGAL libraries. Modifying the generated CGALConfig.cmake file is just a hack.